# Problem with changing culture

Tags: .net, asp.net, resources

I did Override InitializeCulture in base page.

```
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("Fa-IR")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("Fa-IR")
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
```

but still my culture is english united state .
and texts are english yet and are not persian.

---

I want to change it programmatically. I have local and global English and persian resources. i want to switch between them.
How can i fix it?

when i put Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
in main page it works great! but else when i put it in basepage not.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it uncommon that you initialize the base class method with the last line. My first bet was, that this overrides your culture initialization. But I tested it - This isn’t the problem. Your code should work anyway.

Are you sure there is no other place with a culture initialization in your code? CurrentThread is a global variable and if you change it somewhere else (in a web control? in the data layer?) this will influence your page.

Here is my sample code, working for german/english. It should work for persian/english too.

```
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits BasePage
End Class

Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
        MyBase.InitializeCulture()
        Dim cultureInfo = New CultureInfo("de-DE")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thank you.
when i put Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
in main page it works great! but else when i put it in basepage not.
what is the problem?

Comment: If it works in one situation it should work in both situations. Stupid question: There is no empty InitializeCulture without base class initialization in main class if you test for base class?

Comment: Last try. Put my working sample code into the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the culture for your *entire* ASP.NET site then you can do that in the `web.config` file:

```
<globalization uiCulture="Fa-IR" culture="Fa-IR" />
```

See [Localization Made Easy](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/miscellaneous/article.php/c12407) article.

Comment: Thank you.
But I want to change it programmatically.
I have local and global English and persian resources.
i want to switch between them.